# Split All The Listbox Elements And Add Them All To A New String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, split, listbox

I have a problem about my code. I have a listbox and it has items (the number of items unknown). My listbox look like that:

```
                       hello my friends
                       have a good day
                       how r u?
                       I will do it
                       aBcDe
```

And I want to transfer all my listbox items to a string array. After that, I want to split it (parameter=space) according to parameter. So the final look in the array:

{'hello', 'my', 'friends', 'have', 'a', 'good', 'day', how', 'r', 'u?','I','will','do','it','aBcDe'}

It's my code:

```
         char[] sc={' '};
         string[] lb = mylistbox.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
         int cnt = lb.Length;
         for(int c=0; c<cnt; c++)
         {
            //I want to transfer the last array here.
         }
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] lb = mylistbox.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();

//Create a single string which contains all the items seperated by a space
string joined = string.Join(" ", lb); 

//Split the single string at each space
string[] split = joined.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
```

Comment: So I don't need to for loop and length of array, right?

Comment: Correct, no loop needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
var arrayOfItems = listBox.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
var result = arrayOfItems.SelectMany(s=>s.Split(' ')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<string> results = new List<string>();
 for(int c=0; c<cnt; c++)
 {
    results.AddRange(lb[i].Split(' '));
 }


 var stringArray = results.ToArray();
```